# Date range for table Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I currently have this filter on my table

```
  (function(document) {
    'use strict';

    var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

      var _input;

      function _onInputEvent(e) {
        _input = e.target;
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
        Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
          Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
            Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
          });
        });
      }

      function _filter(row) {
        var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
      }

      return {
        init: function() {
          var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
          Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
            input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
          });
        }
      };
    })(Array.prototype);

    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        LightTableFilter.init();
      }
    });

  })(document);
```

I'm wondering how i can use two date fields with this to act as a date range? i have just tried adding two date fields in but that just gives me the response of two exact dates, not the range in between

Heres my html code for the dates

```
<label for="Date">Date From:</label>
              <input type="date" id="datefrom" class="light-table-filter form-control" style="width:50%" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filter">
              <label for="Date">Date to:</label>
              <input type="date" id="dateto" class="light-table-filter form-control" style="width:50%" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filter">
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me. Do you want to filter the table so it only displays the rows with dates that fit in the range of the 2 dates?

Comment: Thats what i'm wanting, This code currently hides the rows that has the search term. Also works on dates, Just not a date range.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will need some expanding of you filter function, but you can compare dates with compare operators like `>=` and `<=`.

So you need to create dates of your 2 input fields and a date of the table row value. You need to identify the cell if it is indeed the date cell, otherwise it will create date objects of arbitrary cell values. I don't know your full HTML, but this can be done by adding a class, for example (see my code).

For example:

```
function _filter(row) {
      var dateFrom = new Date(document.getElementById('datefrom').value);
      var dateTo = new Date(document.getElementById('dateto').value);

      dateFrom.setHours(0);
      dateTo.setHours(0);

      var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(),
        val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
      row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';

      if  (!isNaN(dateFrom.getTime()) && !isNaN(dateTo.getTime())) {
        var cell = row.querySelectorAll(".date")[0];
        var arr = cell.innerText.split('-');
        var rowDate = new Date(arr[0],parseInt(arr[1])-1,arr[2]);
        if (!isNaN(rowDate.getTime())) {
          if (rowDate >= dateFrom && rowDate <= dateTo) {
            row.style.display = 'table-row';
          } else {
            row.style.display = 'none';
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Make sure the `Date` constructor receives valid parsable date formats. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for more info.

**EDIT**
Updated answer and corrected time.

Comment: That didnt work unfortunately. I'll chuck up a js fiddle with your changes in and you can see whwat happens

Comment: Heres the codepen for it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvVmEo (with your changes inside) This actually end up breaking the standard search filter

Comment: Ah lol, I used jQuery, but you're doing plain Javascript. Oldskool, I've updated the answer and the fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNqVRa
It might need some refactoring though, but the idea is there

Comment: Yep working now, Just the original question isn't haha! Still need to get the date range working :)

Comment: I added a `date` class to the date cells in the HTML. You should add it in your original code

Comment: Hi, Check the code link , If i do 20/10/15 to 29/11/15 it only shows one row, It should show more than that :)

Comment: Updated the fiddle. It is because months are zero-indexed (e.g. January is 0, December is 11), dates were shifted off by 1 month.

Comment: Got one more issue with this, Its currently causing some issues, IF i do a search, say 15/10/2015 to 22/11/2015 it shows two results (there should be alot of results) IF i increment the 22 up to 31, Every result shows. Ideas?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I updated the fiddle by adding some extra rows with different dates, and it shows all of the dates within range when selecting 2 dates.